# Is this sentence correct? I am confused

Tags: grammar

> "When are we going to appreciate that vaccines are the single greatest human invention, that have saved billions of lives."

Is it right to use the singular "invention" here? If yes, should it be has instead of have?

Comment: _Vaccines_ agrees with the plural verb _are._ _Invention_ should be kept as such. You might consider dropping that comma, though. And _that_ in the relative clause  refers to the antecedent _vaccines_, thus favouring _have._

Comment: If, however, you wish to use _has_ instead of _have_, you've got to write _which_ instead of _that_ in the sentence. The comma in that case mustn't go out.

Comment: If you're worried about mixing plural and singular, you could always say "vaccination" instead of "vaccines", although it's a bit uglier and less snappy in my opinion. (People often talk about inventions in the singular, as "television", "the vaccuum cleaner", or "radar", but in this context the plural is fine because you're not talking about a single invention but several related things invented by different people: you might also say "Computers are the greatest invention".)